# sql - Select records from one table that do not exist in the other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select all the records from the table "users" that do not exists in the table "clubs". However, the sentence is still showing some records that exist in the table "clubs".

Table: Users

```
ID, Name, Registration_Date
***************************
3, Mark, 5/1/2017
7, Paul, 5/2/2017
8, John, 5/3/2017
```

Table: Clubs

```
************
User_ID, Club_Name
  3, Chicago
  3, Texas
  7, Miami
  7, San Antonio
```

This is the SQL sentence:

---

```
SELECT 
    [Users].[ID], 
    [Users].[Name]
FROM 
    [Users]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Clubs]
ON 
    [Users].[ID] = [Clubs].[User_ID]  
WHERE
    [Clubs].[User_ID] IS NULL AND
    [Users].[Status] = 'Active' AND
    [Users].[Gender] = 'Female'
GROUP BY 
    [Users].[ID],
    [Users].[Name]
ORDER BY 
    [Users].[ID] DESC
```

This is the result that I am getting

---

```
8, John
3, Mark
```

For some reason, the user with ID 3 is still showing, which exists in the "clubs" table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to select all the records that do not exist in club you are better off with a simple `<>` query

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried with that before, however, it did not work as I also have another where conditions associated, like status = active and gender = female. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Check if there is an extra space (or something like that) in either table for the id field for the "3" records, which may cause it not to match correctly. I've recreated that DB locally and the query worked for me.

Comment: Your query is correct for what you want to do.  I suspect you are misinterpreting the data.  "John" and "Mark" are not names usually associated with females.

Comment: James, I just checked for that. All columns are int and did not notice any difference.

Comment: Gordon, I put those names just for testing. I will change it to avoid confusion. thank you for checking!

Comment: James, I found the problem. It was a space in the column Status. I checked the ID column before. You were right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the resolution to the problem provided by James:

> Check if there is an extra space (or something like that) in either table for the id field for the "3" records, which may cause it not to match correctly. I've recreated that DB locally and the query worked for me. –

The problem was a space in the column Status.

I added this comment as the right answer was provided as a comment, and did not find any other option to accept the comment as the right answer.

Comment: No this cannot be. A space in the `Status` column cannot cause the row to be in the resultset. If anything, more rows would be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

It reads like English: Select from User where User.Id is not in Clubs. Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    [Users].[ID], 
    [Users].[Name]
FROM 
    [Users]
WHERE
    [Users].[Status] = 'Active' AND
    [Users].[Gender] = 'Female' AND 
    [Users].[ID] not in (select UserID from Clubs)
ORDER BY 
    [Users].[ID] DESC
```

More info about the [IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

Comment: Thank you for your query. I just tried it. Now, it returns the user ID # 7 as well.

Comment: That is not possible based on the data you have posted. How about this query what does it return: `select * from Users where ID not in (select User_ID from Clubs)`

Comment: It returns this: 8, John, 5/3/2017

Comment: Then I am not sure why the query is returning 7 as well. It is not possible. I had a typo in my answer it should be `select User_ID from Clubs` but you probably fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    [Users].[ID], 
    [Users].[Name]
FROM 
    [Users]
WHERE
    [Users].[ID] NOT IN (SELECT [Clubs].[User_ID] FROM [Clubs]) AND
    [Users].[Status] = 'Active' AND
    [Users].[Gender] = 'Female'
GROUP BY 
    [Users].[ID],
    [Users].[Name]
ORDER BY 
    [Users].[ID] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this. Same result. For some reason it still shows the user id # 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Query**

```
SELECT 
[Users].[ID], 
[Users].[Name]
FROM 
[Users]
WHERE
[Users].[ID] IN 
(SELECT [Users].[ID] except (SELECT UserId from Clubs group by Clubs.UserId)) 
AND
[Users].[Gender] = 'Female' AND
[Users].[Status] = 'Active' // other filters as necessary
ORDER BY 
[Users].[ID] DESC
```

*May need to do an execution plan, may not be perfomant, but gives you the necessary result*

Comment: Thanks for your sentence Jaya. I just tried it. Same result. :(

Comment: @Mark : Updated the query using `Except`

Comment: It continues returning the ID # 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT [Users].[ID], [Users].[Name] 
  FROM [Users]  
  WHERE not exists(Select 1 from [Clubs] where [Clubs].[User_ID]=[Users].[ID]) 
  AND [Users].[Status] = 'Active' 
  AND [Users].[Gender] = 'Female' 
  GROUP BY [Users].[ID], [Users].[Name] 
  ORDER BY [Users].[ID] DESC
```

User ID not exists in the Club table and do exists in the Users table will be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the left join.

Change this:
FROM 
    [Users]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Clubs]

For this:
FROM 
    [Users]
RIGHT JOIN 
    [Clubs]